# Android: Read contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am developing an application in which i am able to read the contacts. I refereed [this Link.](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/06/get-phone-contacts-details-in-android_6.html)

My code to read contact and basic information is as follow:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    String contactID = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
}
phones.close();
```

Now I want to get the following things from contact as :

1.Type of contact as it is of **Device, sim, google, face book** etc contact.

2.The **number of email** for particular contact.

3.Total **account(Face book, whats app, skype etc) count** for the contact.

4.Total **Event(Birthday, anniversary etc)  count**.

5.The **contact is favorite** or not

6.The **contact is in any device group(Family, Friends)** and yes then which groups?

I searched on google but not able to do the desired task.

Please suggest me what should i do.

Comment: Please don't down vote if somebody is unable to answer.

Comment: Dont down vote the question if you are not having knowledge about the question or having great knowledge about it. Do not show your kindness here.

Comment: read documentation of `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds`

Comment: Since my answer may be deleted by the forum police, here it is in the comment:

Try the Android developer tutorial. It does most of what you require with good explanations.

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html